# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-faq-component'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-hooks

I am trying to use [react-faq-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-faq-component) but having an issue. I've more or less copied the same example as that in the link (with additional typscripting).

So far, my code looks like:

**index.tsx**

```
import React from "react"
import Faq from "react-faq-component"

interface PropTypes {
    data: {
        title: string,
        rows: [{
            title: string,
            content: string
        }]
    },
    styles: any,
}

const data = {
    title: "FAQ (How it works)",
    rows: [
        {
            title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
            content: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed tempor sem. Aenean vel turpis feugiat,
              ultricies metus at, consequat velit. Curabitur est nibh, varius in tellus nec, mattis pulvinar metus.
              In maximus cursus lorem, nec laoreet velit eleifend vel. Ut aliquet mauris tortor, sed egestas libero interdum vitae.
              Fusce sed commodo purus, at tempus turpis.`,
        },
        {
            title: "Nunc maximus, magna at ultricies elementum",
            content:
                "Nunc maximus, magna at ultricies elementum, risus turpis vulputate quam, vitae convallis ex tortor sed dolor.",
        },
        {
            title: "Curabitur laoreet, mauris vel blandit fringilla",
            content: `Curabitur laoreet, mauris vel blandit fringilla, leo elit rhoncus nunc, ac sagittis leo elit vel lorem.
            Fusce tempor lacus ut libero posuere viverra. Nunc velit dolor, tincidunt at varius vel, laoreet vel quam.
            Sed dolor urna, lobortis in arcu auctor, tincidunt mattis ante. Vivamus venenatis ultricies nibh in volutpat.
            Cras eu metus quis leo vestibulum feugiat nec sagittis lacus.Mauris vulputate arcu sed massa euismod dignissim. `,
        },
        {
            title: "What is the package version",
            content: "3.2"
        },
    ],
}

const styles = {
    // bgColor: 'white',
    titleTextColor: "blue",
    rowTitleColor: "blue",
    // rowContentColor: 'grey',
    // arrowColor: "red",
}

const config = {
    // animate: true,
    // arrowIcon: "V",
    // tabFocus: true
}

export default function Faq({ data }: PropTypes) {
    return (
        <Faq
            data={data}
            styles={styles}
            //config={config}
        />
    )
}
```

However, when I run `npm start`, I get the following error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-faq-component'.
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-faq-component` if it exists or add a new declaration
> (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-faq-component';`

I've even run `npm i --save-dev @types/react-faq-component` as it suggests, but the error I get thereafter is:

> ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-faq-component - Not found

Comment: The @types packages comes from the repository: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Some packages may not include typescript declarations in itself, and the package owners opt to include it into the DefinitelyTyped repository instead.

This package probably doesn't have typescript declarations, and thats why you cant install it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. So what would I need to do in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as the suggestion says , we have 2 options to solve it.

1. Install the types file. (Not working in this case).
2. Create a .d.ts file and declare the module inside it.

Inside `src` folder create a new file like, `exports.d.ts` and inside it write

```
declare module 'react-faq-component';
```

There is a third option too. Inside the tsconfig file make `"noImplicitAny"` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you! I've used the "noImplicityAny" method and it's worked. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: So, when Typescript is not able to determine the type of a variable, declarations, etc, it falls back to the type "any". However there are cases when such implicit any assumption by TS may cause problem. To prevent that, noImplicitAny is set to true, which tells TS to not determine the type of any untyped variable.